# Mixing and converting wav files to one mp3 file

Tags: c#, naudio, lame

I have 2 wav files. It should convert them to one mp3 file using naudio and lame.exe. Note that the wav file should be created by **mixing** 2 wav files (**not concatenating**).

*two wav files => one mp3 file*

```
 private void MixWavFiles(string[] inputFiles, string outFileName)
        {
            int count = inputFiles.GetLength(0);
            WaveMixerStream32 mixer = new WaveMixerStream32();
            WaveFileReader[] reader = new WaveFileReader[count];
            WaveChannel32[] channelSteam = new WaveChannel32[count];
            mixer.AutoStop = true;

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                reader[i] = new WaveFileReader(inputFiles[i]);
                channelSteam[i] = new WaveChannel32(reader[i]);
                mixer.AddInputStream(channelSteam[i]);
            }
            mixer.Position = 0;
            WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile(outFileName, mixer);

        }



private string ConvertWavToMp3(string wavFileName)
        {
            string mp3FileName = Path.ChangeExtension(wavFileName, "mp3").Replace(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "c:");
            string commandLine = " -V2 " + wavFileName + " " + mp3FileName;

            var lamaProcessInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            lamaProcessInfo.Arguments = commandLine;
            lamaProcessInfo.FileName = WavToMp3ConverterFileName;
            lamaProcessInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;

            using (var lamaProcess = Process.Start(lamaProcessInfo))
            {

                lamaProcess.WaitForExit();
                int exitCode = lamaProcess.ExitCode;
                lamaProcess.Close();
            }
            return mp3FileName;
        }
```

Well, my this is how I'm doing that:

1. First I'm mixing 2 wav files using NAudio and getting one mixed wav
   file.
2. Then I'm converting this wav file to mp3 file using lame.exe.

At the second step `exitCode`  always equals `1` and it means there is an error. So I'm unable to convert wav file (mixed) to mp3 (result) file.

But if I'm converting each of two wav files to two mp3 files it works fine! And `exitCode`  equals `0`. So I have a conclusion the `commandLine` for converting one (mixed) wav file to mp3 file is wrong. Or the mixed wav has the wrong format but it's not most likely because it can be played  by winamp.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: you have created a 32 bit floating point WAV file, which LAME may not handle. Convert back down to 16 bit before creating the Wave file.

Comment: Yes, you're right. But can I create mixed a **16 bit wav** file from two wav files? Lame creates a 32 bit floating  wav file that has 2 channels.

Comment: ??? lame creates MP3 files, not WAV files

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant naudio, the method `MixWavFiles(...)`

Comment: yes there is a Wave32To16Stream (or similar name), that you pass your mixer into and then pass that 16 bit stream to CreateWaveFile